# Mongo: Average on each position of a nested array for multiple documents

Tags: mongodb

I'm recieving an array of documents, each document has the data of some participants of a study.

"a" has some anatomic metrics, here represented as "foo" and "bar". (i.e. height, weight, etc.)
"b" has the performance per second on other tests:
"t" is the time in seconds and
"e" are the tests results mesured at that specific time. (i.e. cardiac rithm, blood pressure, temperature, etc. )

Example of data:

```
[
  {
    "a": { "foo":1, "bar": 100 },
    "b": [
      { "t":1, "e":[3,4,5] },
      { "t":2, "e":[4,4,4] },
      { "t":3, "e":[7,4,7] }
    ],
  },
  
  {
    "a": { "foo":2, "bar": 111 },
    "b": [
      { "t":1, "e":[9,4,0] },
      { "t":2, "e":[1,4,2] },
      { "t":3, "e":[3,4,5] }
    ],
  },
  
  {
    "a": { "foo":4, "bar": 200 },
    "b": [
      { "t":1, "e":[1,4,2] },
      { "t":2, "e":[3,1,3] },
      { "t":3, "e":[2,4,1] }
    ],
  }
]
```

I'm trying to get some averages of the participants.
I already manage to get the averages of the anatomic values stored in "a".
I used:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      barAvg: {
        $avg: {
          $avg: "$a.bar"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

However, I'm failing to get the average of every test per second. So that would be the average on every "t" of every individual element of "e".

Expected result:

```
"average": [
      { "t":1, "e":[4.33, 3.00, 2.33] },
      { "t":2, "e":[2.66, 3.00, 3.00] },
      { "t":3, "e":[4.33, 3.00, 5.00] }
    ]
```

Here, 4.33 is the average of every first test ( e[0] ), but just of the fisrt second ( t=1 ), of every person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to `$unwind` to separate for the documents according to their `t` value and use `$zip` to transpose it before calculating the average:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$unwind: "$b"},
  {$group: {_id: "$b.t", data: {$push: "$b.e"}}},
  {$set: {data: {$zip: {inputs: [
            {$arrayElemAt: ["$data", 0]},
            {$arrayElemAt: ["$data", 1]},
            {$arrayElemAt: ["$data", 2]}
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {
      t: "$_id",
      e: {$map: {input: "$data", in: {$trunc: [{$avg: "$$this"}, 2]}}}
    }
  },
  {$sort: {t: 1}},
  {$group: {_id: 0, average: {$push: {t: "$t", e: "$e"}}}},
  {$unset: "_id"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - zip](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CSyjsKd1808)

Other option may be to `$unwind` twice and build the entire calculation from pieces, but the advantage is that you don't need to literally specify the number of items in each `e` array for the `$arrayElemAt`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {b: 1, t: 1, _id: 0}},
  {$unwind: "$b"},
  {$unwind: {path: "$b.e", includeArrayIndex: "index"}},
  {$group: {_id: {t: "$b.t", index: "$index"}, data: {$push: "$b.e"}}},
  {$sort: {"_id.index": 1}},
  {$group: {_id: "$_id.t", average: {$push: {$avg: "$data"}}}},
  {$sort: {_id: 1}},
  {$group: {_id: 0, average: {$push: {t: "$_id", e: "$average"}}}},
  {$unset: "_id"}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - unwind twice](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6EpaozlKiho)

Comment: thank you, is it possible to add a counter of the amount of documents averaged

Comment: It is possible. If you provide the requested result for the sample data, and choose one of the options in the answer, I'll show you how to change this option according to get to your requested result